# How to identify html elements which doesn't have id and apply it using javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to apply id for html elements which doesn't have id.This will help automatic testing run based on id.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the HTML file as a text file?  Or are you trying to add ids to all elements from Javascript within the web page after the DOM has been parsed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the DOM has loaded, you can do something like this:

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (!elems[i].id) {
        elems[i].id = "_custom_" + counter++;
    }
}
```

This will add id values like this:

```
_custom_0
_custom_1
_custom_2
```

and so on to any element that doesn't already have an id assigned.

---

Note: this is code to look in the body of the document only (assumes you don't want to assign IDs to tags in the `<head>` section), though you could change it to apply everywhere.

Comment: I prefer this because it doesn't require jQuery and guarantees the ID will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a jQuery way.

```js
$('body *:not([id])').attr('id', function(i) {
    return 'someid_' + i;
});
```

```css
[id^=someid]{
  color:red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='e1'>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div id='e2'>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div id='e3'>6</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

Html:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i=1;i<=$('span').length;i++) {
        if (!$('span:nth-child('+i+')').attr('id')){
            $('span:nth-child('+i+')').attr('id','id'+i)
        }
    }
});
```

Don't know if it's recommended though...